# Read from System.in in hh:mm format with delimiter

Tags: java, delimiter

i'm trying to read from the System.in something like this: hh:mm (for example: 17:10, 9:32, etc.)

I also want to store the number before the colon into "hour" variable and the one after into "minute" variable. My code so far is like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter(":|\\n");
    int hour = 0, minute = 0;

    while (in.hasNext()){
            hour = in.nextInt();
            minute = in.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Hour is : " + hour);

            System.out.println("Minute is : " + minute);
        }
```

However, when I run it and type in "9:10" then PRESS ENTER for example, I got this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
```

If i put this instead:

```
    in.useDelimiter(":");
```

then it only reads in the first number (the "hour"), it only reads in the second number (the "minute" when I key in 9:10: (note the second colon).

Could you guys help?

Comment: Are you sure, sure, sure that you're entering exactly and only `9:10`, then press *Enter*? For example, entering `9:10 ` (with an extra space) would produce an `InputMismatchException`, while I believe that `9:10` should work fine. Or maybe you're using *Windows* and when you press *Enter*, `System.in` actually receives `\r` then `\n` or some insane thing like that. I'd suggest you to try again with `in.useDelimiter(":|\\s");`.

Comment: @ccjmne I changed to \s as you suggested, it printed out ok but at the same time the same InputMismatchException is still displayed.

Comment: Can you try `in.useDelimiter(":|\\r?\\n");` then, please? :) If it starts working properly, I'll have understood what's going on exactly and will be able to explain it.

Comment: @ccjmne yes, it worked now without any error. Could you explain it for me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the answers you've given to my comments, I assume that you're using **Windows**.

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, your system actually sends **two** bytes to `System.in`: not only `\n`, but actually `\r` **then** `\n`.

---

Thus, when you're using `\n` or `:` as a **delimiter**, here's what happens:

```
System.in              9:10\r\n
matching delimiters     ^    ^
```

Tokens:

- `9`, which can be coerced to an `int`
- `10\r`, which cannot.

---

However, using `:` or `\r\n` as delimiter would result in the following:

```
System.in              9:10\r\n
matching delimiters     ^  ^
```

Tokens:

- `9`
- `10`

... which can both be coerced to `int`s.

---

It's quite easy to check. The following piece of code will show you the ASCII value of each character read from `System.in`:

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("");

while (in.hasNext()){
    final String next = in.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < next.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(next.codePointAt(i));
    }
}
```

When you execute this and simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> into you console, you should get:

```
13
10
```

... where `13` is the ASCII decimal value of *carriage return* (`\r`) and `10` is *line feed*'s (`\n`) one :)

---

As a side note, I'd like to point out that the **regex** I suggested you in the comments to your question (ie: `:|\r?\n`) will match either `:` or `\r\n` or `\n`.

Thus, it'd also work on `Linux`, for example :)

I hope that this thorough explanation answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to split the line like so:

```
String[] timeParts = in.nextLine().split(":");

System.out.println("Hour is : " + timeParts[0]);
System.out.println("Minute is : " + timeParts[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. But I am still trying to understand why mine doesn't :P

Comment: @NgocQuangVu Good! I invite you to consider the acceptance of my answer if it suits your question. Otherwise, have you tried to change the type of variables `hour` and `minute` to `String` and, instead of `nextInt()` to `next()` ?

Comment: I need to use the hour and minute as integer so i parse using Integer.parseInt() for both. :)